# What Oracle privilege is to be granted to a role so it allows users to see tables in Oracle SQL Developer schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Using Oracle 12c, I have a role which I have granted basic CRUD operations to using Oracle SQL Developer. The problem is, users of the group can not see the list of tables in Oracle SQL Developer. All they see is the branch that shows a tables node but there is no plus sign to expand and see the tables for the one schema they need to work with.  What other privilege needs to be granted to the group so they can see all the table nodes for their schema when using Oracle SQL Developer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they going to Other Users, Tables node? They'll never see it on the main tables node if they are not logging in as the schema owner where the tables 'live' https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you

- created a role
- granted certain privileges to that role
- created bunch of users
- granted role (from step 1) to those users

but they still don't see anything.

If that's so, they won't see anything regardless of what you grant - it is because they don't have those objects in theirs schemas.

What you (or they) should/could do is to precede table name with owner name while selecting data from those tables. Suppose that there's a table named `EMPLOYEE` and your users want to select data from it - they should run `select * from robertcode.employee` (presuming that user `robertcode` owns that table)

Although it *works*, users won't be happy because they don't know table names. Therefore, create a script which they will run in their schemas - that script will create **synonyms** to your tables.

In order to do that, write query which will create query:

```
SQL> select 'create synonym ' || table_name || ' for ' || table_name ||';'
  2  from user_tables;

'CREATESYNONYM'||TABLE_NAME||'FOR'||TABLE_NAME||';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create synonym EMP for EMP;
create synonym BONUS for BONUS;
create synonym SALGRADE for SALGRADE;
create synonym DEPT for DEPT;
```

Copy/paste all those `create synonym ...` statements into an e-mail message and let them create synonyms for themselves.

They still won't see anything under the **Tables** node (because those users don't have tables (until they create them in their own schema), but will see something in **Synonyms**.

Comment: There is an option on the filter dialog to include synonyms for showing tables

Comment: That's a nice option, @that! Thank you for the information!